# Constructor / Self-reference for instance variables

Tags: java, refactoring

How to best refactor a constructor in Java, which instantiates member/instance variables, which need a reference to the class which is going to be constructed/instantiated? I want to pass the dependency in the constructor as a parameter, to enable unit testing of methods which call methods on the instance variable.

Basically it boils down to something like this:

```java
final class Foo {
  private final Bar bar;
  ...

  Foo() {
    bar = new Bar(this);

    ...
  }
}
```

However, all dependencies should be given by dependency injection / per parameter.

Edit: My idea would be adding a factory as a parameter to the constructor and then call a method which passes this in a createInstance method in the methods, which use the instance variables:

```
final class Foo {
  private final BarFactory factory;

  Foo(BarFactory factory) {
    this.factory = Objects.nonNull(factory);
  }

  public void bla(String fooBar) { 
    final Bar bar = factory.create(this); 
    ...
  }
}
```

So I can mock the factory.

Comment: Refactor to do what? I mean, I'd try to eliminate the need for a cyclical reference, but it's unclear what you're trying to achieve specifically.

Comment: It is not clear what the question requires.

Comment: It allows me to write unit tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track in avoiding this:

```
final class Foo {
  private final Bar bar;
  ...

  Foo() {
    bar = new Bar(this);

    ...
  }
}
```

All initialization of an object should occur in a constructor, therefore you can potentially pass an uninitialized object to `Bar()` as construction of `Foo()` may or may not be complete by that point. Of course, if you are passing a reference this shouldn't be an issue but still a bad practice and as you mentioned, you won't be able to easily mock `Bar()` depending on which mocking framework you are using.

You have a couple options:

1. Use a factory within methods as you have listed.
2. [Lazy load](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LazyInitialization.html) `Bar()` when it is needed with a factory.
3. Use [Setter Initialization](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SetterInitialization.html)
4. Invert the dependency. I.e., whichever code is dependent on the methods that `Foo()` needs `Bar()` for, have the `Foo()` consumers
   just use `Bar()` instead of `Foo()`. This could end up with the cleanest domain but also may be the most work.

   - I.e., change `var x = Foo.blah()` to `var x = Bar.blah()`.

You have a lot of options to choose from and there isn't any "best" answer, just what makes sense based off of your domain. Any of the above works and only looking at your question as written, I'd go with Lazy Loading or inverting the dependency.

Comment: I'll use the lazy loading with a factory I guess. It's for instance about https://github.com/sirixdb/sirix/blob/master/bundles/sirix-core/src/main/java/org/sirix/access/PageReadTrxImpl.java   ... back then from the days at the university, but yeah, I think I'm on the right track, after refactoring this and a few constructors which are about the same crap (doing a lot of work instead of just retrieving instance parameters).

Comment: Specifically the caches for instance... but I'll similarly "fix" the loading of the revision root page and the reading of the index definition initialization stuff.

Comment: By the way if anyone feels like he/she has to refactor something... go for it, as I still think it's a great project.